# Сделать несколько replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, синтаксис

Есть строка, например `<p:+79993333311@example.com>`, где +79993333311 это номер телефона, причем он может быть в разных форматах, предлагаю на этом не зацикливаться... В общем его нужно извлечь, мы знаем что все остальное примерно постоянное, предлагаю следующий  код:

```
    var item = '<p:+79993333311@example.com>'; //может быть 79993333311 или 89993333311 или 9993333311 или еще что то
    let phone = item.replace(/\s+/g,'');
    phone = phone.replace('<sip:','');
    phone = phone.replace('@','');
    phone = phone.replace('example.com','');
    phone = phone.replace('>','');
```

Мне лично это все очень не нравиться и мне кажется можно сделать проще, и я не об этом:

```
        let phone = item.replace(/\s+/g,'');
        phone = phone.replace('<sip:','');
        phone = phone.replace('@example.com>','');
```

Такое решение суть моего вопроса не меняет.
Регулярное выражение на пол экрана то же не вариант.
Как можно решить эту задачу более рационально и красиво, нежели те решения что я предложил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну примерно, так:

```js
var item = '<p:+79993333311@example.com>';
console.log(item.replace(/<p:(.+)@.+/,'$1')); // +79993333311
```

Если не знаем какой тег между `<` и `:` (и если вдруг есть пробелы или другие символы) то можно сделать например так:

```js
var item = '< tag :+79993333311@example.com>';
console.log(item.replace(/<[^:]+:(.+)@.+/,'$1')); // +79993333311
```

Answer (score -1):

Напомните, почему нельзя просто найти подстроку по крайним элементам без всяких replace и регулярок?
Думаю, такой способ быстрее и проще.

```
let phone = '<p:+79993333311@example.com>'
console.log(phone.substr(phone.indexOf(':') + 1, phone.indexOf('@') - 3))
```

Comment: интересная, идея, я об этом не подумал

Comment: Ну и тут по выбору, надо или нет убирать `+`, если он есть

Comment: Ваш вариант, будет работать медленее, чем даже мой 2 пример. `substr+indexOf: 1.302978515625ms
replace1: 0.1328125ms
replace2: 0.135986328125ms`

Comment: @And тут три действия против Вашего одного, так что это ожидаемо.